# How to parse ElasticSearch JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json, elasticsearch

I've parsed basic JSON files with no trouble before, but the structure of this one (from ElasticSearch) is completely confusing me. Here's a stripped down example of the JSON I'm working with:

```
{
  "took": 7,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 2,
    "successful": 2,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1017,
    "max_score": 2.8167849,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "myindex",
        "_type": "mytype",
        "_id": "119479",
        "_score": 2.8167849,
        "_source": {
          "title": "my title",
          "url": "my url",
          "company": "my company",
          "location": "my location",
          "description": "my description",
          "industry": "my industry"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "myindex",
        "_type": "mytype",
        "_id": "119480",
        "_score": 2.8167849,
        "_source": {
          "title": "my title",
          "url": "my url",
          "company": "my company",
          "location": "my location",
          "description": "my description",
          "industry": "my industry"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Now, let's say I want to get the 'title' value of both results result. I have tried a lot of different things with no success. For example:

```
//json_decode works fine. I have verified with a var_dump();
$myobj = json_decode($json);
//this is where I'm not sure what to do:
foreach($myobj->hits->hits->_source as $result) {
    echo $result->title;

}
```

I've tried a lot of different variations, but I'm just not exactly sure how to parse this structure. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: `var_dump($myobj)` will show you the exact structure.

Comment: Thank you, that got me on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

As Marc B stated, var_dump($myobj) will give you the structure of the json object.

To iterate over the properties of an object use this:

```
foreach($myobj->hits->hits->_source as $key => $val) {
    if($key == 'title') {
        echo $val;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it. Here's the code for anyone who might find it helpful later on:

```
foreach ($myobj->hits->hits as $result) {
echo $result->_source->title;
}
```