# PHP parsing of a multi-dimensional array from Elastic Search

Tags: php, arrays, elasticsearch

I have this multi-dimensionnal array called `$response` (**I only get one result but there are many in reality**..)

```
Array
(
    [took] => 17
    [timed_out] => 
    [_shards] => Array
        (
            [total] => 5
            [successful] => 5
            [skipped] => 0
            [failed] => 0
        )

    [hits] => Array
        (
            [total] => 16
            [max_score] => 13.034995
            [hits] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [_index] => zh3
                            [_type] => zone_humide
                            [_id] => 4950467
                            [_score] => 13.034995
                            [_source] => Array
                                (
                                    [surfcal_ha] => 2.26
                                    [@timestamp] => 2019-01-21T19:25:48.826Z
                                    [@version] => 1
                                    [donnee_id] => 3355
                                    [zhu_cbi] => 82
                                    [zh_nom] => Coupigny
                                    [gid] => 4950467
                                    [zh_part_id] => 079FONTEN0011
                                    [is_pe] => 
                                )

                        )
                )

        )

)
```

I want to get the **gid** attribute. To do that, I tried :

```
foreach ($response['hits']['hits'][0]['_source'] as $result) {
echo $result['gid'];
}
```

But I get that PHP Warning :

> PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'gid'

I tried different things.. add another foreach loop, change the echo but nothing works. I tried [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23117561/how-to-parse-elasticsearch-json-in-php) coming from StackOverflow but no results too.  Well I think I'm really stuck.

Any ideas on that problem ?
Any help would be very appreciated ! 
Thanks

Comment: I've added an answer for you. Is it helped ?

Answer (score 2):

`$response` array has only one parent element. Why do you use `foreach`?

Just try

```
echo $response['hits']['hits'][0]['_source']['gid'];
```

Answer (score 0):

it is because you are using foreach on `$response['hits']['hits'][0]['_source']`
eg. 1.in first loop of foreach it will get`$result['surfcal_ha']` 
2. in second loop it is getting  `$result[@timestamp]` 
so till it doesnt get `$result['gid']` it will print warning.Try using below without foreach

```
echo $response['hits']['hits'][0]['_source']['gid'];
```